# How to upload a "fair use" image to Wikipedia - Wikimedia does not allow it

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I gave up trying to find how to upload an image allowed by the press dept.

I read in [one place in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Non-free_content) that I could use

```
{{Non-free promotional}} {{Fairuse}}
```

but it is probably not what they meant on the page

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:UploadWizard

What would be the correct way to be allowed to upload an image I have permission to?

[Rationale for allowing the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Use_rationale_examples): it is the poster from the performance in the article about the performance.
The image file was given to me by their press secretary.

I just simply cannot figure out how to upload the image to wikimedia to be able to use the rationale

Comment: This isn't a question on how to use Wikipedia as much as it is about Wikipedia's policies. To be honest, you'll do better to ask this question at the [Wikipedia Help Desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk). It looks like the information you need is probably at [Wikipedia:Use rationale examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Use_rationale_examples).

Comment: I did ask. No answer. Link to the WIKIPEDIA upload instead of the WIKIMEDIA upload worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Fair use" media files are not allowed on Commons

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Fair_use

If you want to include a fair use image in Wikipedia, you'll have to use the local language variant of Wikipedia. For the English Wikipedia, the policy is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Non-free_content and to upload it you can use [Wikipedia:File Upload Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:File_Upload_Wizard) to upload to Wikipedia.

Btw: If *you* are the copyright holder, you have the power to license it in a way that Wikimedia Commons allows it. I recommend asking your legal department.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:File_Upload_Wizard would be the place you can use to upload to Wikipedia.